# Why do I get the error "Use of Unassigned local Variable"?

Tags: c#

I have this code below :

```
string mybytes(int[] sbytes)
{
    string bytesss;
    for(int i=1; i< sbytes.GetUpperBound(0)+1;i++)
    {
        bytesss += "," + IntToHex(sbytes[i - 1]).ToString();
    }
    return bytesss;
}

private string IntToHex(int number)
{
    return string.Format("{0:x}", number);
}
```

Why does it keep raising "Use of Unassigned local Variable" error ?

Comment: Ask yourself - what does the `bytesss += ...` opcode do?

Comment: that should be a warning

Comment: @codingbiz, that is an error, not a warning

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler wants you to `provide value to string variable before you use it`, What if it `does not go in the for loop as compiler does not know whether control will go in for loop` during execution.  If control does not go in for loop method will return unassigned variable which compiler does not like and gives you error. You are `using the value of variable before assigning it due to += operator` so you will `get error due to this over here`. Assigning empty string could prevent us from compilation error as statement given below assigns empty string.

```
string  bytesss = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Even when entering the loop, it would still be an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Hilgarth, overlooked it due to +=, updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're local variable called bytesss is not being initialized before you try to concatenate to it. Doing this is similar to trying to concatenate a string to null, it just doesn't make any sense. Consider the following code.

```
string bytesss = null;
bytesss += ",";
```

or to put it another way...

```
string bytesss = null + ",";
```

Neither of these things make sense, so you need to make sure bytesss is set to some initial value before trying to concatenate. For example:

```
string bytesss = "";
```

or

```
string bytesss = string.Empty;
```

Lastly, there's a few other things you can do to make your code easier. If you're using a recent version of the .NET framework and have LINQ you can do something like this:

```
string mybytes(int[] sbytes)
{ 
    return string.Join(",", sbytes.Select(i => IntToHex(i)).ToArray());
}
```

or if you're using an older version you could do something like this:

```
string mybytes(int[] sbytes)
{ 
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach(int i in sbytes)
        list.Add(IntToHex(i));

    return string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string bytesss;

should be

string bytesss = String.Empty;

try that.

Comment: It's complaining because you didn't initialize bytesss, so it doesn't know what kind of initial value to give it.

Comment: you should edit your answer to include your additional statement, posting as a comment is usually not ideal

Answer (score 0):

Well, you never initialize `bytesss` in your code.

Change it to this:

```
string bytesss = "";
```

There are actually two problems in your code:

1. If `sbytes.GetUpperBound(0)` returns 0, your loop will never be entered, so `bytesss += ...` will never be executed.
2. Even when the loop is entered, you still have a problem. `bytesss += ...` is equivalent to `bytesss = bytesss + ...`. But what is `bytesss` in the first iteration of your loop? It is undefined, because it never has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the string without initialising it. Try declaring it as "string bytess = String.Empty;" instead. [This essay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your code. It solves the issue.

```
string  bytesss = string.Empty;
```

or

```
string bytesss = "";
```